# Still show the proper set of time even if there's no entry for that time

Tags: mysql, time, time-series, missing-data

I have this query where it gets the average and group the values by 15 mins from 12 AM to 11:45 PM.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(t_stamp/1000, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p') as t_stamp,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '001' THEN value END),2) Value1,   
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '002' THEN value END),2) Value2,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '003' THEN value END),2) Value3

FROM table1
WHERE tagid IN ("001", "002", "003") and

date(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) BETWEEN "2014-05-01" AND "2014-05-01"

GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000))  DIV 15
```

The output looks like this

```
    t_stamp             |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3
05/01/2014 12:00 AM     |   199     |   99      |   100
05/01/2014 12:15 AM     |   299     |   19      |   140
05/01/2014 12:30 AM     |   399     |   59      |   106
05/01/2014 12:45 AM     |   499     |   59      |   112
.
.
.
05/01/2014 11:00 PM     |   149     |   199     |   100
05/01/2014 11:15 PM     |   599     |   93      |   123
05/01/2014 11:30 PM     |   129     |   56      |   150
05/01/2014 11:45 PM     |   109     |   60      |   134
```

It works fine but I've noticed that sometimes if there's no entry for like the time 12:30 instead of showing

```
    t_stamp             |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3
05/01/2014 12:00 AM     |   199     |   99      |   100
05/01/2014 12:15 AM     |   299     |   19      |   140
05/01/2014 12:30 AM     |   Null    |   Null    |   Null
05/01/2014 12:45 AM     |   499     |   59      |   112
```

It will show the set of time like this:

```
    t_stamp             |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3
05/01/2014 12:00 AM     |   199     |   99      |   100
05/01/2014 12:15 AM     |   299     |   19      |   140
05/01/2014 12:33 AM     |   122     |   141     |   234
05/01/2014 12:45 AM     |   499     |   59      |   112
```

What I would like to happen is when there's no time for that 15 min group it will still show the proper set of time and then just show null on the column values. The output I would like is like this:

```
    t_stamp             |   Value1  |   Value2  |   Value3
05/01/2014 12:00 AM     |   199     |   99      |   100
05/01/2014 12:15 AM     |   299     |   19      |   140
05/01/2014 12:30 AM     |   Null    |   Null    |   Null
05/01/2014 12:45 AM     |   499     |   59      |   112
```

How can I do this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that's a source of cardinal numbers as a start for this. For the moment let's assume it exists, and it's called `cardinal`.

Then, you need to create a query (a virtual table) that will return rows with timestamps every fifteen minutes, starting with the earliest relevant timestamp and ending with the latest.  Here's how to do that for your query.

```
SELECT '2014-05-01' + INTERVAL (cardinal.n * 15) MINUTE as t_stamp
  FROM cardinal
 WHERE cardinal.n <= 24*4
```

Then you need to JOIN that virtual table to your existing query, as follows

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp.t_stamp, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i %p') t_stamp,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '001' THEN value END),2) Value1,   
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '002' THEN value END),2) Value2,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN id = '003' THEN value END),2) Value3
  FROM table1 AS t
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT '2014-05-01' + INTERVAL (cardinal.n * 15) MINUTE as t_stamp
          FROM cardinal
         WHERE cardinal.n <= 24*4
       ) AS t_stamp 
         ON t_stamp.t_stamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(t.t_stamp/1000)   
 WHERE tagid IN ("001", "002", "003")
   AND date(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) BETWEEN "2014-05-01" AND "2014-05-01"
 GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), 
          HOUR(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)), 
          MINUTE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000))  DIV 15
```

Notice that the LEFT JOIN makes sure the rows will NULL values from your original query get included in the result set.

Now, where does this magical `cardinal` table come from?

You can generate it as two views, like this.  This particular view generates numbers from 0 to 100 000, which is more than enough for quarters of hours for a year.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cardinal10 AS
    SELECT 0 AS N UNION
    SELECT 1 AS N UNION
    SELECT 2 AS N UNION
    SELECT 3 AS N UNION
    SELECT 4 AS N UNION
    SELECT 5 AS N UNION
    SELECT 6 AS N UNION
    SELECT 7 AS N UNION
    SELECT 8 AS N UNION
    SELECT 9 AS N;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cardinal AS
    SELECT A.N + 10*(B.N + 10*(C.N + 10*(D.N + 10*(E.N)))) AS N
    FROM cardinal10 A,cardinal10 B,cardinal10 C, 
         cardinal10 D,cardinal10 E;
```

Here's a writeup on the topic.
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/